# Why does the rand() return always the same number?

Tags: ruby

I am using

> rand(200)

in my Rails application.
When I run it in console it always returns random number, but if I use it in application line:

```
index = rand(200)
```

index is always **the same number**.

Why is that and how to overcome this?

Comment: Does Ruby have a random seed function?  Typically you have to "seed" a random number generator with something.  If you don't do this, it will start with the same seed and create the same list of random numbers each time you use it.

Comment: try `srand; rand(200)`

Comment: Look through your application for use of `srand` or possibly something re-defining `rand`.

Comment: the 'index' variable has been assigned rand(200).  So whatever was returned will always be the value of 'index' unless you intentionally change it.

Comment: @matt it didn't help :/

Comment: @PhillipKregg and I am hoping it will stay the same value! :) (I am calling the action multiple times, and every time the same rand is assigned to the index)

Comment: @matt it did help :) (after) I have tried again, and your suggestion did work! :) thank you. You can add an answer and I will select it as answered if you would want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple pseudo-random number generators actually generate a fixed sequence of numbers. The particular sequence you get is determined by the initial "seed" value. My suspicion is that you are always getting the first number in the *same* sequence. Therefore I suggest we try to change the sequence by calling `srand` every time before calling `rand`, thus changing the seed value every time. The [docs explain](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-srand) that, when called without a parameter, `srand` generates a new seed based on current circumstances (e.g. the time on the clock). Thus you should get a difference sequence and hence a different random number:

```
srand
rand(200)
```

Now, you may ask - *why* are you always getting the same sequence? I have no idea! As someone else suggested in one of the comments, the behavior you are seeing is the behavior one would expect if you had other code, anywhere, that calls `srand` with the *same, fixed* value every time. So it might be good to look for that.

Comment: Thanks for putting it like this, now I could have reference in the future, and other can see it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `Random.rand()`.  For example

```
Random.rand(200)
```

Or if you're working with an array you could use `sample`.

```
[*1..200].sample
```

Comment: Thanks, but at the end I have solved the problem with @matt 's suggestion. And Random.rand, I didn't have access and I didn't want to add a new requirement, so I have just used `srand`. Thanks for the suggestion in any case ;)

Answer (score -1):

rand(200) is run once and that value is assigned to your `index` variable.  So 'index' will always be that number.

If you want `index` to change, you will need to continually run rand on it.

Here's a simple way to do that:

```
def randomIndex(num)
  index = rand(num)
  return index
end

randomIndex(200)
=> // this value will change
```

Comment: I know :) I have put in the comments as well. I am hoping the value will stay the same when I assign it :) I am calling action where I generate random number, but each time on this whole day it is generating the same number.

Comment: @Aleks I'm not quite sure what you are asking for.  Why are you running rand on a number that you want to stay the same?

Comment: `index = rand(200)`
I wouldn't want for index to change in between :)
`a = array[index]`